# Jenkins not showing updates/plugins available

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I installed Java 1.8.0_72 along with tomcat 8 and jenkins 1.6, i currently having problems with installing plugins because the jenkins update center has no plugins/update available. I tried installing plugins manually on jenkins home path/plugins

Is there any other way? or any idea how to configure http proxy?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the proxy setting here: `http(s)://<server-URL>/pluginManager/advanced`

Keep in mind that an enterprise proxy (NTLM / NTLMv2 authenticating) might not work and that you might have to use something like `cntml`

For more information check:
[cntlm SourceForge page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cntlm/)

Comment: It eventually displayed the plugins but it took a long time. Maybe they are too many.